# What amount of current (heat) can a pre-charge resistor handle?

Tags: resistors, pre-charge

I am designing a pre-charge circuit for an electric vehicle. I have a 50 W, 100 Ω resistor, and the capacitors in whole system are 1 mF in total. That gives me about 210 J of energy dissipated during the entire time of the precharge.

Would this fry the resistor? Is this a viable solution for long-term use?

Comment: 210 J over how long time?

Comment: To what voltage it is being charged, what is the initial surge current and is the resistor rated to handle it?

Comment: Well according to calculations its 0.5s.Battery voltage is 650V, resistor is ~1200V.

Comment: Link the datasheet for the resistor. And pay attention to its pulse rating.

Answer (score 1):

Peak power is over 4kW (almost 100x steady-state rating). There's a chance the resistor won't just fry, it might literally explode.

I strongly suggest you pick a resistor **with a pulse power rating** that fits your application, either from datasheets or from consultation with the manufacturer's engineering department. [Here](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1773277&DocType=DS&DocLang=English) is a 50W chassis mount resistor, and, as you can see, the manufacturer thinks it's only good for 10 or 20J.

[image]

There is also a plot of allowable overload vs. time, which again comes up short by a large margin:

[image]